Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality Proof in $\mathbb{R}^n$
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$ where $x_i$ are positive real numbers. Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i} \geq n^2
$$
The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, assuming the inner product is the dot product, on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as
$$
\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\Big)^2 \leq \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\Big) \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2\ \Big)
$$
the solution provided for this answer states that for $\mathbf{x} = \big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}} .. \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}}\big)$ and $\mathbf{x} = (\sqrt{x_i} .. \sqrt{n})$ then this provides a valid solution. However, I am not sure as I think the LHS of the CS inequality does not work, i.e,
$$\begin{align}
\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\Big)^2 & = \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}} \sqrt{y_i}   \Big)^2 \\
& = \Big(n - 1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{x_i}}\Big)^2
\end{align}$$
Could someone please confirm if I have missed something or if I am correct that this does not hold?
Edit: If I were to instead assume that $\mathbf{x} = \big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}} .. \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_{n-1}}} 1\big)$, this would then hold I think but would be grateful if someone could confirm. Thanks!

try $\mathbf{x} = \big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1}} .. \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}}\big)$ and $\mathbf{y} = (\sqrt{x_1} .. \sqrt{x_n})$

This works! Thanks a lot.
